Purge Google Cloud Build History
Is it possible to purge old builds from the build history.
We have no need to keep history older than a month, I thought storing the logs in a user created bucket would help, but this only affect the logs themselves not the history

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

With Google Cloud, there are no charges associated with storing build results. Your build history is permanently preserved within your project unless the project is deleted and the history is cleaned up by Wipeout.
You can check this document for pricing: https://cloud.google.com/build/pricing
It looks like as of now there is no option to delete build history.And if you have project requirements, you can raise a feature request under public issue tracker

You cannot delete build logs in the Google-created logs bucket. To delete build logs in a user-created logs bucket:

Grant the Storage Object Admin role to the user or the service account deleting logs.
Delete the build logs using the instructions to delete Cloud Storage objects in Deleting objects.

To delete the user-created logs bucket:

Grant the Storage Admin role to the user or the service account
deleting the logs bucket.
Delete the logs bucket using the instructions to delete a bucket in Deleting buckets.

For the artifacts, there’s no gcloud command to delete a build artifact/image. If they are stored in Google Cloud Storage, you can delete them by this guide, and if they are in Google Artifact Registry this one can solve it.

I'm not looking to delete the logs, I'm talking about the actual build history themselves
Deleting the logs does not delete the history of the build itself.
I'm talking about this list
gcloud builds list
